# Password protect a set of pages using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

Inside my `views` folder I have a folder named `admin` and inside this I have various PHP pages. Now on my homepage and other pages as part of the nav menu, there's a link that says `Admin`. What I basically want is all pages inside the `admin` folder to be password protected but not sure how I'd do it correctly?

I'm not entirely sure why it's not working as intended.

The directory I want to password protect is `/home/myuser/public_html/ci/application/views/admin/.htpasswd`

In my model I have:

```
public function admin()
    {
        //load in a model
        $this->load->model("products");
        $data['results'] = $this->products->getAllProducts();


        //load the view
        $this->load->view("admin/adminhome.php", $data);
    }
```

Then the `Admin` is linked to in the navbar like this:

`<li class='last'><a href='/myuser/ci/index.php/site/admin'><span>Admin</span></a></li>`

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
AuthName "Secure Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/to/your/directory/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

Have a look here:
http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/password-protect-directory.shtml

Comment: I tried doing this but for some reason it didn't work. Do the `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` have to be inside the directory you want to password protect?

Comment: In principle yes, but it can also be at higher levels, up to your root directory.
If you have access to your /etc/apache2 directory, you can put the code at the host configuration file (/etc/apache2/sites-available)

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure why it's not working. Inside the `views` folder is the `admin` folder and there's an `adminhome.php` page inside that. I tried putting the `.htaccess` inside there but I can still click on the `Admin` link in the navbar and it takes you to the `adminhome` view without asking for a username/password

Comment: There's a number of things you should check.
First of all, are you sure mod_rewrite is enabled? (check http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)
Secondly, did you create .htpasswd correctly? (check http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html)
Thirdly, are you sure you are seeing adminhome.php directly? (maybe adminhome.php is called from somewhere else?)

Comment: Yeah I'm not entirely sure why it's not working. I've created the `adminhome.php` page, placed that inside the `admin` folder in the `views` folder and then defined the view in the model but there's no password prompt anywhere on the site.